# JavaPNS Push Notification with sound enabled

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have made a web app for sending Push Notification to iOS devices. I am using JavaPNS library for this, but I couldn't understand how to set sound while sending notification.
As per JavaPNS doc, while preparing `PushNotificationPayload` and adding sound using `void addSound(String sound);` method, I passed value as **default**. I am recieving notification but without sound alert. I checked with device with all other precautions. (like disabling silent and default tone as Tri-tone).  below is my code:

`PushNotificationPayload payload = preparePayload(badge, sound, key,    value, alert,contentAvailable);`

inside `preparePayload()` method I am just doing some validation with parameters and assigning the values like `payload.addSound(sound);`

Im pushing through:

`PushedNotifications obj = Push.payload(payload, certificate,passwd, Boolean.parseBoolean(production),(totalThread < 10 ? 10 : 10), listOfDevices);`

Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register for push notifications in your app delegate, you specify which types of notifications your app will accept. Make sure that `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound` is one of the types you specify.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {

   // other setup tasks here....

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

}
```

Comment: Thanks Eran, I will try with this.